# Multiple hosts prompt is working but there's a problem with execution

Tags: ansible

This is my code:

```
---

 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: no
   vars_prompt:
     - name: server
       prompt: "What is the hostname/ip you want to execute at?"
       private: no
   tasks:
   - add_host:
       name: "{{ server }}"
       groups: dynamic_hosts
     with_items: "{{ server.split(',') }}"
   #### Dynamic Host
 - hosts: dynamic_hosts
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
      - name: "Running task id"
        command: id
```

and this is the behaviour:

```
What is the hostname you want to execute at?: 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [add_host] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item= 10.0.0.2)
changed: [localhost] => (item= 10.0.0.3)

PLAY [dynamic_hosts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Running task id] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3: Name or service not known\r\n", "unreachable": true}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/user/playbook.yaml

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

So the input of multiple hosts is working properly but when I try to call the group in hosts basically it tries to "ssh 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3" and naturally it fails.

What am I missing here?
What I want to do is prompt the user for the hosts he wants to execute at, input
and then just execute the tasks to each host. I do not want to make use of an inventory file.
Is it possible? Thank you in advance

Comment: => `name: "{{ item }}"`

Comment: Hey @Zeitounator thanks I got it now. I ll update code. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
---

 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: no
   vars_prompt:
     - name: server
       prompt: "What is the hostname/ip you want to execute at?"
       private: no
   tasks:
   - add_host:
       name: "{{ item }}"
       groups: dynamic_hosts
     with_items: "{{ server.split(',') }}"
   #### Dynamic Host
 - hosts: dynamic_hosts
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
      - name: "Running task id"
        command: id
```

thank you